# Value of lambda in poisson distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am currently studying statistical estimators and I came across a question that asks to give an estimate of the parameter **λ** of a Poisson distribution (using the method of moments), given that the following sample is obtained:

> 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 0, 0, 1, 4, 1, 5, 2, 1, 2, 0

It's easy to see we can equate  λ to the arithmetic mean of the sample, and we get:

$$ \lambda =\frac{46}{20} = 2.3$$

Now, this is where I stopped solving, certain that I had obtained an answer. However, the book I'm using states that 'therefore' the answer is 2, but it doesn't go on to explain why.

Could this be a mistake or is there valid reasoning for the answer being 2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Beats me.  Your computation is correct as written.  There is no intrinsic reason why the parameter $\lambda$ should be an integer; it is only the support of the Poisson random variable itself that must be a nonnegative integer.  The method of moments estimator is $\tilde \lambda = 2.3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X\sim\mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$ then $\mathbb E[X]=\lambda$. From the method of moments, equating the sample mean and population mean we get $\hat\lambda=\overline X$. So your reasoning is correct. Another estimator can be obtained by

$$\tilde \lambda = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2 -\left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)^2, $$
as also $\operatorname{Var}(X)=\lambda$. But this yields $\hat\lambda=2.21$. I don't know where the point estimate 2 comes from.

Answer (score 2):

As you've observed, the method of moments estimator for the mean of a Poisson is just the sample mean, $2.3$ in your case. (The maximum likelihood estimator - which I suspect you're likely to come across soon, if you're learning about the method of moments - is the same for the Poisson but is not necessarily the same in general.)  A Poisson random variable always takes on integer values, but its parameter value $\lambda$ doesn't need to be an integer.

Now, the mode of the Poisson($\lambda$) distribution is $\lfloor \lambda \rfloor$, which would be 2 -- but that's not what was asked.  Your textbook is wrong. It happens - textbook authors are human.